# SQL WHERE is an array

Tags: sql, ms-access

Forgive me for not finding an answer and taking some of your time.

I'm trying to use all the rows in `table2.column` to make the query in `table1.symbol`

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE table1.Symbol = table2.column;
```

I've tried

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE table1.Symbol ='$table2.column';
```

it ran but gave me no results.

I tried the IN but couldn't make a multiple search of all the rows in table2.column.

Thanks for the Help.

Comment: You need to join the tables. Please take a SQL tutorial first to get around such basic questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `JOIN`

```
SELECT table1.*
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.symbol = table2.column
```

If there can be multiple matches, this will return repeated rows. You can solve that by using `SELECT DISTINCT table1.*`.

You can also do it with `IN`

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE symbol IN (SELECT column FROM table2)
```

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that if any value is repeated in `table2`, the two queries don't have the same effect.

Comment: OK, I addressed that.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used  IN. Such speedy answer.